# Facebook SDK for android not working with keystore/key

Tags: facebook, sdk, unity-game-engine, keystore

I'm having some problems with the facebook sdk for android.

Everything works fine till I add a keystore/key in Player Settings -> Publish Settings.

When I build the .apk without a keystore/key everything works fine i can log in to facebook and use all the functions no problem. But after I have made a keystore/key so I can upload the app to Google Play it suddenly stops working

I have also try it with the Facebook SDK example InteractiveConsole and the same happens. The little white box
at the bottom says "Login cancelled by Player". I think this problem has to do with the Debug Android Key Hash.

I have been stuck on this problem for like a week now, I have google it alot and have come across threads saying tha unity takes the wrong Debug Android Key Hash. That is why I used Facebook-Unity-Fix uploaded by Kabe0 on https://github.com/Kabe0/Facebook-Unity-Fix.

After using the Facebook-Unity-Fix instead of the normal facebook SDK for unity, I got a different Debug Android Key Hash, so I replaced the Debug Android Key Hash in my App -> Settings -> android -> Key Hashes (In the Facebook Developer Site). with the new Key Hash that i got.

But the same problem still happens "Login cancelled by Player". I am officially out of any ideas how to fix this. Can someone please help me out.